# How to engage textView on app launch swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I am making a calculator with my own keypad and i need the textview to be engaged on create, any ideas or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Sorry, I'm new to iOS

Comment: Do some research on `becomeFirstResponder`

Comment: @Shank by engaged i mean make it as though the user has tapped it

Comment: @rmaddy thanks that worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `becomeFirstResponder` of your `TextView` on View will appear.

For example: `TextView.becomeFirstResponder`

Answer (score 0):

```
   myTextView.becomeFirstResponder
```

did the trick